# LEGO Mindstorms EV3 crashes on OS X El Capitan

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, software, mac

I get the following problem details, can anyone help me?

```
Process:               MindstormsEV3 [595]
Path:                  /Applications/LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/MindstormsEV3
Identifier:            ___ev3.lego.com
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MindstormsEV3 [595]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-01-02 19:49:06.678 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        7C4B40A6-2FAA-BA7A-5740-01D0F51AF6AB


Time Awake Since Boot: 2100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00080148
Trap Number:     132
```

Comment: I don't see anything useful here. Is this the entire crash report? (looking for a stack trace - that is the most useful part). Also, try running `/Applications/LEGO\ MINDSTORMS\ EV3\ Home\ Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/MindstormsEV3` in a terminal and see if there is any extra output in the terminal.

Comment: The crash report was seen by this community as spam and  could not be posted. I removed en reinstalled silverlight and this solved the problem,

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have Silverlight plugin on your mac:

1. Access your hard drive
2. Double-click the hard drive icon on your desktop
3. Find the plugin
4. Navigate to your Internet Plug-Ins directory: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/

If installed:

1. Remove the plugin
2. Drag any of the following into your trash bin:

   - Silverlight.plugin

Then dowload and install the Silverlight plugin from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

If not ok remove and reinstall Mindstorms software.

Comment: I removed en reinstalled silverlight and this solved the problem, thanks

Comment: This solved my problem as well on Mojave... this was driving me crazy. Hanging with nearly every action.